# Flushable kitty litter...should I flush it or is it bad for my plumbing?

Tags: plumbing

I rent an apartment in California. I flush my kitty litter because it is flushable.

Is flushing kitty litter not good for your plumbing even though the litter was designed to be flushed down the toilet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting question and it is all in the wording.  Flushable meaning can it be flushed?  Yes.

Does it break down like human waste?  I doubt it.  So yes you can flush it.  Will it cause plumbing issues?  Maybe.  It really depends on the size of the litter and how long it take for it to break down.

Real-world experience...  My plumbing contractor has had more than a couple jobs because of litter clogging pipes, especially iron pipes.

This question is kind of like asking should you flush kleenex or baby wipes - you can but they can cause issues.  The only thing that should go in your toilet is human waste and toilet paper.  These things break down easily.

Comment: [Are “Flushable” baby wipes flushable?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/are-flushable-baby-wipes-flushable)

Comment: There needs to be another term.  Anything of a certain size is flushable.  Will it pass through your plumbing without causing issues is a different story.  I just switched my iron to pvc 2 months ago.  I can say for sure that wipes clogged our old pipes.